# The first checkbox on the page checks itself on and off whenever I click somewhere on the page

Tags: php, html

As the title suggests, I have an issue concerning checkboxes, I create multiple checkboxes to the site using a foreach loop that looks like this:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $i => $item ){
    $quant = $item->get_quantity();
    $unitprice = $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity();
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" . " " . // wrapped
    $item->get_name() . " | " . $item->get_total() ."; $i'>";
```

and when I attempt to select one, if I don't click directly inside the box, or I change a numerical value created by this:

```
if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
    echo "Määrä: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty[" . $i . "]' value='" // wrapped
                . $quant . "'max='" . $quant . "' min='1' > " . "<br/>";
}
```

the html side before the loop

```
   <p class="selectall">Valitse kaikki tuotteet</p>

   <label>Tilauksessa tulleet tuotteet:</p>
   <br />
```

inside the same foreach, it always selects or deselects the very first checkbox printed to the site, it also selects/deselects the first checkbox if I click anywhere on the page after the first checkbox has been created, be it just text of a number selector. How do I fix this issue and what actually causes such problems so I can avoid them in the future?

Comment: This is a question about the output html rather than the PHP. Add your resulting html to your question, it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: can you explain a little in what way? the visual output or? in what way exactly should I show it. @SimonBrahan

Comment: The HTML code and any JS as it appears in your browser. You can access this in chrome by right clicking on your page and clicking `View page source`.

Comment: Your `<label>` is never being closed

Comment: it was closed after the loop it seems, but the label itself was the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the label from

```
<p class="selectall">Valitse kaikki tuotteet</p>

<label>Tilauksessa tulleet tuotteet:</p>
<br />
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: No problems mate :)